# Can I take a byte from MIPS register?

Tags: string, assembly, char, mips, mars-simulator

To take a string from user input you can do:

```
la $a0, destination
li $a1, 120
li $v0, 8
syscall
```

but if I want to store string into register (not in memory) can I do any syscall to do this?

If I can, in which way can I take the first or another character from it?

Comment: how you expect to fit a string in a register?  how small is your string?

Comment: If you want to read a single character from the user, use system call 12 (the character will be returned in `$v0`). For string input the destination must be memory.

Comment: there's "read char" syscall in MARS IIRC, to read single character. And you can "take" any bits of the register you wish, for example if you are interested into bits 16-23 ("third" byte of register), you can do `srl $t1, $t0, 16` `andi $t1, $t1, 0xFF` and you will end with b16-b23 from `t0` as byte value (b0-b7) in `t1` (with upper b8-b31 bits zeroed). But you can fit only information about 4 bytes at most into single register (32 bits / 8 bits = 4 bytes), so you can put "string" into register only if it is very short.

Comment: I added an operating system tag (`mars-simulator`). MIPS runs on many operating systems, each of which have a different set of syscalls.

Comment: @RaymondChen: You said that backwards (or with a stray "on").  Many OSes *run on MIPS*, each having different syscalls and/or a different ABI for accessing them.  MARS and SPIM system calls have a compatible subset, but yeah tagging MARS is close enough; that's what this question is about.